# Harmonic sequence in C

Tags: c, math

```
void harmsec(){

    int n = 1;
    float y = 1;
    printf("Harmonic sequence: ");

        while (y >= 0.11){
            printf("%.2f", y);
            printf(", ");
            n = n + 1;
            y = 1*(1/n);
        } /*while*/
        if (y < 0.11){
            printf("%.2f", y);
            printf("\n");
        }/*if*/
}/*harmonic sequence*/
```

I'm wondering whats wrong with my code here, trying to output a harmonic sequence. Output is only 1.00, followed by 0.0.

Comment: As several have noticed, `(1/n)` is integer division.  You don't need to multiply it by 1, even if it is a float.

Comment: Why not `printf("%.2f, ", y);` and `printf("%.2f\n", y)` in place of the pairs of `printf()` calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/n is done as integer division, and n is 2 first time so 1/2 = 0 and y goes to zero.

Change 1/n to 1./n which will then calculate the division in floating-point precision.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

`y = 1*(1./n); //make the result as float`

Answer (score 1):

```
void harmsec(){

int n = 1;
float y = 1;
printf("Harmonic sequence: ");

    while (y >= 0.11){
        printf("%.2f", y);
        printf(", ");
        n = n + 1;
        y = 1*(((double)1)/n);
    } /*while*/
    if (y < 0.11){
        printf("%.2f", y);
        printf("\n");
    }/*if*/
}/*harmonic sequence*/
```

Comment: Using a cast instead of `1.0` seems a little clumsy, as does multiplying by `1` (though that was in the question).  Personally, I don't like the `1.` notation used in the other answers; I was brought up to think there should be digits on both sides of the decimal point to ensure no ambiguity.  The compiler OTOH does not care.